# Need help checking if else statement for { }

Tags: php, if-statement

Somewhere along the line I'm adding or leaving out a { } but I just can't figure out where

```
<?php
if (file_exists('config.php')) {
   require_once('config.php');
    {
        if ( $EDITED_CONFIG == false ) 
            {
                header("Location: welcome.php"); 
            }
    }
}
else (file_exists('default-config-new.php')) {
    require_once('default-config-new.php');
    {
        if ( $EDITED_CONFIG == false ) 
        {
        header("Location: welcome.php"); 
        }
    }
}
```

?>

If file exists require it and if edited = false redirect, if true end script.

else

If file exists require it and if edited = false redirect, if true end script.

So if the first file doesn't exist it mustn't require it or look for edited, it must skip to the second file and if that exists it must checked edited and then if is false then redirect. If the first file is true it must end script and load page. So it mustn't check second file if first file is true.

Also is this the lightest way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

If you indent your code properly, your error will become evident.

A few links that may be useful:

- [Wikipedia: Indent style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style)
- [How to indent code](http://www.rkeene.org/projects/info/wiki/163)
- [PHP Coding standard: Indentation](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/PHP+Coding+Standard+%28draft%29#PHPCodingStandard%28draft%29-Indentation)

Comment: I have it indented in notepad just a mission to do here. One question. Do I have to close the first if { before or after the else?

Comment: Yes. You write it like `if (condition) { true statements } else { false statements }`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not closing your if statements: Should be something like:

```
<?php
if (file_exists('config.php')) {
  require_once('config.php');
  if ($EDITED_CONFIG == false) {
    header("Location: welcome.php"); 
  }
}
else{
  require_once('default-config-new.php');
  if ($EDITED_CONFIG == false) {
    header("Location: welcome.php"); 
  }
}

?>
```

Edited. Also, you need to close brackets around all code to be executed for that statement, before you can use another elseif or else statement:

```
if ($x == 1) {
  echo "X is 1!";
}
else if ($x == 0) {
  echo "X is 0!";
}
else {
  echo "Not 1 or 0!";
}
```

Comment: I don't want the second file exists to happen unless the first one doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the { after the else to enclose what you want inside the "else" block i believe

Answer (score 0):

You need to write

```
else if (conditions...)
```

You have got

```
else (conditions...)
```

Comment: you may want to change `statement` to `condition`.

Comment: Ah someone noticed! You passed the test... =/